# hadoop.dll file location for Spark 3.3.1 on Windows

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, windows-10

I want to run Spark 3.3.1 on Windows 10. That's why I had to download winutils.exe and hadoop.dll for Hadoop 3.3.
I must save hadoop.dll in `C:\Windows\System32` to avoid this Spark error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
```

I want to know if there's a way to change the hadoop.dll path, so I won't need admin rights to save a file in System32 directory.

Comment: have you tried setting environment variable `HADOOP_HOME`?

Comment: @mazaneicha I don't think setting that will do anything about native files, especially dll files

Comment: Another thing to try -- add `<winutils>\bin` to PATH env  var.